# How can I locate all symlinks which reference a directory?

Tags: directory, symlink, samba

I recently discovered that directory symlinks and samba are a bad mix.

Now I want a script which will list all symlinks which point to directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -H . -type l -exec find -L {} -type d \;
```